# Implement a redirection

Tags: c

One of my exercice asks to implement a redirection, when the child reads from **file descriptor 0** then he must the read file descriptor **desc**

```
int redirection(int desc)
    {
        int pipe[2];
        pid_t pid = fork();
        if (pid == 0)
        {
            dup2(desc, 0);
        
        }
    }
```

does **dup2(desc, 0);** correspond to what it's asked ?

Comment: nit: if you `dup2(desc, 0)`, subsequent reads from file descriptor 0 will read from the same file description as reads from file descriptor `desc`.  But they are not reading from the file descriptor `desc`.  Reads from either file descriptor will read from the same file description.

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/195057/what-is-an-open-file-description

Comment: You don't need the `pipe`. The caller might pass some `pipe[0]` to your function as `desc`.